# Setting up Lan within a Lan

Tags: networking, router

How unreasonable would it be to setup a small LAN within an existing LAN?   I'm setting up a series of video surveillance servers and a number of IP cameras in a client's location and cannot have my equipment on the same network as their local machines.  My network is essentially self-contained and the only device that anyone needs to access is a web-app on one of the machines.

Basically I'm thinking of installing a SOHO router which would uplink to their LAN, and then set up some NAT rules on both their router and my router, to allow outside access to the webserver.

Is there anything fundamental that i'm missing which would prevent this from working?

Comment: Do they have switches that will support vlans?

Comment: Probably, but my main goal in this setup is to minimize any contact with their existing LAN.  I have very little support from their existing IT staff, if anything, they're deliberately un-cooperative.  Also, my systems could end up using a high amount of bandwidth, which i don't want to affect their existing network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, nothing missing. If anything, it's too complicated.

The easiest way to achieve this is to make the webserver multi-homed, i.e. it has one network interface in the video LAN and another in the company LAN. As long as this machine does not route traffic, nothing can go wrong. If the vhost for the web-app is set to respond to all IP addresses, it will be available on both LANs. No router required, no NAT.

If you need access to the web-app from outside that company, then the main router of the company (the one that gives them Inernet access) would need to have a port forwarding rule in place (from public IP port whatever to web server company IP port 80).

Comment: multi-homed webserver. it's brilliant!